# How to configure spring batch jobs modular?

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

I'd like to defined mutiple `Jobs` in my `spring-batch` application, and trying to make them modular as follows:

```
@Configuration
@EnableBatchProcessing(modular = true)
public class ModularConfig {
    @Bean
    public ApplicationContextFactory getJob1() {
        Sysout("job1");
        return new GenericApplicationContextFactory(Job1.class);
    }

    @Bean
    public ApplicationContextFactory getJob2() {
        Sysout("job2");
        return new GenericApplicationContextFactory(Job2.class);
    }
}
```

From the sysout I can see both job beans are created.

BUT: when one of those jobs is launched, the `@Beans` of that job cannot be found.

```
public class Job1 {
    @Bean
    public Job job(Step step) {
        return jobFactory.get("job1")
                .start(step)
                .build();
    }


    @Bean
    public Step step(ItemReader<String> reader, ItemProcessor<String, String> processor, ItemWriter<String> writer) {
        return stepFactory.get("importStep")
                .reader(reader)
                .processor(processor)
                .writer(writer)
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    @JobScope
    public IteamReader<String> reader(@Value("#{jobParameters['filename']}") String filename) {
        //returns a FlatFileItemReader<String>
    }

    //omitted also `@Bean` for processor + writer
}
```

Result: the `reader` is not found in the job configuration! Why?

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'reader' is defined
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanDefinition(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:698) ~[spring-beans-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getMergedLocalBeanDefinition(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1175) ~[spring-beans-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getType(AbstractBeanFactory.java:596) ~[spring-beans-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.GenericTypeAwareAutowireCandidateResolver.checkGenericTypeMatch(GenericTypeAwareAutowireCandidateResolver.java:95) ~[spring-beans-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.GenericTypeAwareAutowireCandidateResolver.isAutowireCandidate(GenericTypeAwareAutowireCandidateResolver.java:64) ~[spring-beans-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.QualifierAnnotationAutowireCandidateResolver.isAutowireCandidate(QualifierAnnotationAutowireCandidateResolver.java:142) ~[spring-beans-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.isAutowireCandidate(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:687) ~[spring-beans-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.isAutowireCandidate(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:646) ~[spring-beans-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.isAutowireCandidate(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:630) ~[spring-beans-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1191) ~[spring-beans-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1116) ~[spring-beans-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1014) ~[spring-beans-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:813) ~[spring-beans-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:741) ~[spring-beans-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    ... 34 more
```

So why may the reader not being found? I mean: what can I do more than naming the bean method itself `reader()` and also inject it with variable name `reader`?

Sidenote: when I remove the modularty and just use  `@Configuration` on `class Job1` then job runs fine. So I'm quite sure the configuration of the job and the reader should be correct. But of course I cannot run a similar jobclass beneath, so I'd like to have modularity enabled.

---

Edit: when I enable the `@Configuration` annotation on my jobs, I'm getting a duplicate job name exception. That's why I'm not having it in the code above.

```
Caused by: org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.DuplicateJobException: A job configuration with this name [job1] was already registered
    at org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.support.MapJobRegistry.register(MapJobRegistry.java:51) ~[spring-batch-core-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.support.DefaultJobLoader.doRegister(DefaultJobLoader.java:258) ~[spring-batch-core-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.support.DefaultJobLoader.doLoad(DefaultJobLoader.java:193) ~[spring-batch-core-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.support.DefaultJobLoader.load(DefaultJobLoader.java:151) ~[spring-batch-core-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.support.AutomaticJobRegistrar.start(AutomaticJobRegistrar.java:173) ~[spring-batch-core-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
    ... 16 more
```

Answer (score 1):

Without `@Configuration` beans on `job1` won't be registered. Please have a look at this test case [Test Configuration](http://www.massapi.com/source/github/83/13/831305292/spring-batch-core/src/test/java/org/springframework/batch/core/configuration/annotation/JobLoaderConfigurationTests.java.html#usePkgClazzLink)

Comment: I your testcase is valid, then it's strange I'm getting a `DuplicateJobException` when I enable `@Configuration` additionally to the modular registration. See my update above.

Comment: @membersound in your application do you registrer configuration classes manually or you scan a package ? I think you shouldn't scan the job config classes and let GenericApplicationContextFactory register it

Comment: I'm using `spring-boot` with `@SpringBootApplication` which automatically scans the packages. So you'd suggest I'd exclude the package with the job configurations?

Comment: @membersound just the Job class

Comment: If I do that, and have the jobs registered only by `ApplicationContextFactory`, I'm getting the exception again: `NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'reader' is defined`.

Comment: can you try registering it manually to `AutomaticJobRegistrar `

Comment: Registering the jobs manually without having `@Configuration` on the job itself, I'm getting again the exception: `No bean named 'reader' is defined`. If I add `@Configuration` to the job, it works **but** the job `@Bean` is somehow created twice (but without name clash). Then, when trying to invoke the jobs, there name is not found.

Comment: I created a simple example with 2 jobs that should be running modularized:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0qVi9D7R5MZOTE3ME9xdHdKNms/view?usp=sharing

There are two problems in the project:
1. even though the two different jobs execute, both seem to be using the `reader` from `job2`.
2. as soon as I enable the `ModularBatchConfig` class, the project is not starting up anymore.

Maybe you could help fixing this example so that both jobs can be running modular?

Thanks for your time!